# Is there any way to force a migration of my question from one site to another?

Tags: support, specific-question, migration

I asked [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/130407/how-can-i-set-automatically-update-the-title-in-an-xterm-running-screen) on superuser, but I think it is more appropriate to ask it on stackoverflow.  Since it's my question, I can delete it from superuser without any moderator privileges and just re-ask it on stackoverflow.  However, that doesn't seem to be the trilogic way.  Is there any way for me to force my own question to migrate from one site to another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nathan, I honestly think that the question you've asked is a question about *application configuration*, and that Super User is the appropriate site for it.  It's well stated, and it's *exactly* the kind of question I think Super User is for.

Now, the applications you're configuring do have some use in programming, and the SO community can give you answers faster than SU can.  That's not a great reason to post it there, IMHO, but I can't stop you.

So I won't migrate that question for you.  But if you want to repost to SO, go ahead -- if the SO community migrates it back to SU, the two can be merged together, and it's quite likely you'll get answers on SO before the question gets migrated.

Please do *not* delete your original SU copy.

Thanks!

---

**Edit**: On the topic of mechanisms a user can use to effect a migration on his own, there are three:

1. Flag for moderator attention and ask for a migration.
2. Vote-to-close the question as belongs-on-SX (for some X in {OFUM}).
3. As you've noted, you can also delete it on the first site and re-ask on the destination site.  Less useful if your question has already gathered upvoted answers, though, and less desirable because you circumvent any community review of the migration choice.  But it uses the site tools already in existence, so I don't know how "non-Trilogic" this method is.

One or both of the first two options may have a minimal rep requirement, but I get both options on my SO questions, and I've only got 300 rep there.  So they are available, if not to all questioners, to all but the newest users.

Comment: Good point, and I agree that maybe my example was a poor one.  However, it's highly probably that questions will be posted in the wrong site.  If the subject isn't popular and the tags are obscure, it's unlikely to be flagged for moderator attention.  I'm suggesting a mechanism that would allow question owners to do it for themselves.  I mean, if I can decide ahead of time that a question is more appropriate for one site than for another, shouldn't I be allowed to change my mind?  Nobody knows my intent better than me (I hope).

Comment: @Nathan - but nobody knows the sites better than people who spend a long time each day on them. So the OP is the one who knows the question, but in most cases he won't know which site is for which. This is how most misplaced questions happen, finally.

Comment: @Nathan: you should be able to flag your own question for moderator attention.  when you reach a certain rep threshold, you can cast a vote to migrate your own question.  those are the pre-existing mechanisms for doing what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

While the process of moving a question over by the person who posted the question seems like a nice feature, in reality it would be (and should be!) used very little:

- If the author realizes it's in the wrong place, they should realize that long before pressing "Submit"
- If the author doesn't realize it's in the wrong place, then it'll be moved for them, and this option wouldn't have helped anyway.

Given that the author can usually delete the question and re post it, there's no need to create this function.

The only situation where it might be valuable to have this function is if the author posted the question thinking it fit best on X, but after a few answers pointing out solutions that came from another realm, or helped define the question better, the author came to a new understanding about the question and decided it would be better off someplace else.

In that rare instance, especially when an answer has been upvoted and the question can't be deleted, flag the question for moderator attention and use the comment box, "Please migrate to Y."

I don't think that a feature allowing users to do this would add significant value to the site.

Comment: If the question already has answers, then deleting and reposting will delete the answers. In fact, will the system even allow me to delete a question with answers?

Comment: "If the author realizes it's in the wrong place, they should realize that long before pressing "Submit"" - Not necessarily.  You're assuming too much about the users.

Answer (score 1):

Just flag it for moderator attention stating that you think the question would be better suited on Stack Overflow. If he agrees, he'll migrate it.

Or better yet, let the community act. Of course, letting the community migrate questions works better, or merely faster, on Stack Overflow than on Super User.

Answer (score 1):

Users can be wrong in which site they ask their question on. That means they can also be wrong in which site they would choose to migrate it on.

As told, it's not possible currently, flag a moderator. I don't think this is a feature which should implemented, though, as it would be easy to migrate a question on any site then, and spam all the trilogy with it, just for fun.

This operation should remain only for moderators and 5 votes from 3k users (and the later is already abusing it).

Answer (score 0):

No, but this is a great idea.